# How do you detect whether a player has two of a specific item in their inventory, and then delete one?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to recreate the old Missile Wars Mini-game in Minecraft Bedrock edition, and I've come across a problem that's stumped me; detecting if a player has 2 of the same stackable item, and then clearing the 2nd item so that the player only has 1.
I'm not the most knowledgeable person on Minecraft commands, so that's why I've come here to ask.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We appreciate the effort here

Comment: I tried a few things with `/clear @a dirt 0 0`, none of none which worked.